# Make font of some rows in a datagridview bold

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I'm just trying to force the font styling of certain rows within my datagridview to be bold but I can't seem to get it to work.
I don't know where I'm going wrong on this, seems like a simple thing that shouldn't be causing any issues.
I've even put in a message box for debugging just so I know the program is going into the if statement.

Is there a property that needs to be set to allow row font formatting or something?

Any help appreciated, thanks.

**Code:**

```
//apply row  formatting
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvTasks.Rows)
            {
                //get title of current row
                string rowTitle = row.Cells["#"].Value.ToString();

                //check if title is digit
                if (rowTitle.All(char.IsDigit))
                {                    
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Arial", 15.0F, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

                    MessageBox.Show("test");
                }
            }
```

Comment: I suspect the problem is that your rows are not being redrawn. Try putting your `if (rowTitle.All(char.IsDigit))` code within the `dgvTasks.RowPrePaint` event. You can reference the current row in that event like this: `dgvTasks.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells["#"].Value.ToString()`

Comment: Did you do any cell formatting? (which I think takes pecedence over row formatting) - Otherwise your code works just fine.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I've just put the formatting code within the DataBindingComplete event and it now looks to be working. Like you said, the rows were not being redrawn so the any formatting should be done once you've finished adding any initial data.

Answer (score 1):

`dgvTasks.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Arial", 15, FontStyle.Bold);`

This is a fully-functional code snippet that works to change the font of specific row of dataGridView.

I think that there is a problem with your if() loop or the event you put your code in.

Comment: @AndroidCB:    I think your problem is resolved, so pls accept this as the answer so the thread is closed.